# Is a carrying handbag on arms Lo Yilbash on a man

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, yoreh-deah, lo-yilbash, gender

According to Halacha, is it lo Yilbash (cross dressing) for a man to carry  a handbag or purse on his arm? Or is  there any heter for men to have them if they need it for storage?

Comment: It's not a purse, it's European!

Comment: It probably isn't lo Yilbash to carry anything. Otherwise no one  could pick up clothing  of the oppisite gender. Wearing a handbag with the strap  over your shoulder like women do is maybe a question

Comment: @shmosel YOU BEAT ME TO IT

Comment: @Schmerel according to some using weapons is not allowed for women...